# View RDLC Report as pdf in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, rdlc

I am facing problem in last two days. I am trying to view rdlc report as pdf without reportviewer. I export rdlc to pdf using the following code...

```
public string Export(LocalReport rpt, string filePath)
    {
        string ack = "";
        try
        {                
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;

            byte[] bytes = rpt.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            return ack;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ack = ex.InnerException.Message;
            return ack;
        }           
    }
```

The pdf file exported to User->AppData->Temp

```
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
            string ack = Export(rpt, Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Mymun_Lab/ComparisonStudy.rdlc"));                
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

I want to render this pdf file to the client PC.

This Code is work fine on my local machine. But when i publish this to IIS Server and run for try to get the exported pdf file to client PC not success. How can i solve this issue. Can anyone help me.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i found one solution about view RDLC report as pdf in asp.net MVC. The solution is following....

```
public FileResult ViewReport()
    {            
        string RptPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Mymun_Lab/ComparisonStudy.rdlc");                  
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport rpt = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport(); 

        /* Bind Here Report Data Set */

        rpt.ReportPath = RptPath;
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();               
        Export(rpt, filePath);
        //CLOSE REPORT OBJECT           
        rpt.Dispose();
        return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
    }
```

I use the following method for generate pdf from RDLC....

```
public string Export(LocalReport rpt, string filePath)
{
    string ack = "";
    try
    {                
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;

        byte[] bytes = rpt.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return ack;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ack = ex.InnerException.Message;
        return ack;
    }           
}
```

Comment: I get error in return File(filePath, "application/pdf")

Comment: Where you add Export() method? Direct in Controller or separate Class? Do you add proper version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll in your project reference? @ElbertJohnFelipe

Answer (score 1):

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<FileResult> DownloadReport(string id, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var result = await accountRepository.GetUserLogInDetailsByID(id);

    //string RptPath = Server.MapPath("~/RDLC/rptUserLogInDetails.rdlc");
    string RptPath = Server.MapPath("~/RDLC/rptUserLogInDetails.rdlc");

    ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();

    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
    rds.Name = "DataSet1";
    rds.Value = result;

    string companyName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyName"];

    ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];
    parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("username", firstName + " " + lastName);
    parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("companyName", companyName);

    //ReportViewer rv = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
    rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = RptPath;

    // Add the new report datasource to the report.
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    rv.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;

    rv.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);

    rv.LocalReport.Refresh();

    byte[] streamBytes = null;
    string mimeType = "";
    string encoding = "";
    string filenameExtension = "";
    string[] streamids = null;
    Warning[] warnings = null;

    streamBytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

    string fileName = "LogInDetails-" + firstName + lastName + ".pdf";

    // This will download the pdf file
    //return File(streamBytes, mimeType, fileName);

    //This will open directly the pdf file
    return File(streamBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```