# Open RDL report rendered in PDF in a new tab/window in MVC WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rdl

I am trying to create a print function that when Print button is clicked. A new tab or window will open that displays the RDL file in a PDF format.

I found this link that helps me have an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40841394/8245979

But I get error in the **return** on the **FileResult** method maybe because I'm using api. I think it downloads the file instead of just opening it anyway. Can someone help me rephrase the code to achieve my task?

```
    public FileResult ViewReport()
    {            
        string RptPath = Server.MapPath("~/AngularViews/forms/dcf/report/dcf.rdl");                  
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport rpt = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport(); 

        /* Bind Here Report Data Set */

        rpt.ReportPath = RptPath;
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();               
        Export(rpt, filePath);
        //CLOSE REPORT OBJECT           
        rpt.Dispose();
        return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
    } 




    public string Export(LocalReport rpt, string filePath){

    string ack = "";
       try {                
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;

        byte[] bytes = rpt.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return ack;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ack = ex.InnerException.Message;
        return ack; }           
   }
```

Comment: What kind of error you've got when `return File(filePath, "application/pdf")` executed? Include exception message in your question too.

Comment: it's a syntax error in File();